# Erro na configuração do projeto

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, thymeleaf

O que estou errando, não consegui encontrar o erro.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd                
                        ">

    <!-- ONDE ESTÃO OS COMPONENTES DO SPRING (EX:@Controller, @Repository, @Service 
        e @Component ) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.netsoft" />

    <!-- SEM ESSA TAG ELE NÃO RETORNA O JSON -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- SEM ESSA TAG NÃO CARREGA OS CSS/JS -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- GERENCIAMENTO DO JPA PELO SPRING -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PERSISTENCE_UNIT" />
    </bean>

    <!-- gerenciamento das transações -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>DESIF</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

**Log no console**

```
01:19:05,602 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./desif.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./desif.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.desif.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1079)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:284)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module "deployment.desif.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
    ... 6 more

01:19:05,608 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "desif.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./desif.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./desif.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.desif.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet from [Module \"deployment.desif.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./desif.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

Entendi que não existe esta classe org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. Mas como fala springframework.web.não entendi, pois no POM tem spring.

Servidor é Wildfly.

Arquivo pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.netsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>desif</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>desif</finalName>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.1</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>

        <!-- false - não precisa de XML -->
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <!-- Thymeleaf - Layout Dialect -->
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Métodos uteis para manipulação de String, métodos e etc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf - Layout Dialect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf - extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring início -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring fim -->

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- Logging início -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging fim -->

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.inject</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.2.2</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Se você já está usando o Spring Boot, qual o motivo de não utilizar todas as outras configurações do próprio?

Comment: Estou querendo utilizar Spring com Widfly, entende ?